# How do I copy the contents of a textarea to the clipboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

I have an `html markup` thats echoed and is wrapped in a `textarea` and its also a read only like so:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="70" readonly="readonly">text with markup goes here.</textarea>
```

how do I do it that when a user clicked on the read-only text area contents, it will be automatically selected and copied to the clipboard and with a notification that its already copied?

Comment: Using PHP? PHP can't do anything here.

Comment: Search Copy to Clipboard you'll find a JavaScript/Flash solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is server-side so you won't be able to do anything to interact with the client. In terms of client-side then javascript can do something. The bad news is that Firefox doesn't allow this any more as far as I recall (I remember seeing some debate around it regarding TinyMCE's clipboard functionality) so the odds are you'll need something mixing flash and js to get a fully cross-browser solution.

Might I thus suggest http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/ as a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want PHP for that,try this:

```
function copy(inElement) {
 if (inElement.createTextRange) {
  var range = inElement.createTextRange();
 if (range)
   range.execCommand('Copy');
} else {
  var flashcopier = 'flashcopier';
  if(!document.getElementById(flashcopier)) {
  var divholder = document.createElement('div');
   divholder.id = flashcopier;
  document.body.appendChild(divholder);
}
   document.getElementById(flashcopier).innerHTML = '';
   var divinfo = '<embed src="_clipboard.swf"        FlashVars="clipboard='+encodeURIComponent(inElement.value)+'" width="0" height="0"      type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>';
document.getElementById(flashcopier).innerHTML = divinfo;
}
 }
```

```
<form name="formtocopy" action="" >
<textarea name="texttocopy" disabled="disabled">
A whole bunch of text here that will be copied.
</textarea>
<br>
<a href="javascript:copy(document.formtocopy.texttocopy);">Copy the Text!</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Works fine for me.try using 
[zeroclipboard](https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard)

Comment: Where is `_clipboard.swf`? :)

Comment: @Milind I would appreciate if you can post the complete working code. thanks